# Set connection variables based on variable value in inventory before attempting to connect to host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory of mixed RHEL and Windows hosts requiring different Connection variable values. These hosts are sorted into a parent group (their team) and child group (their app).

I could have them in multiple groups: "RHEL"/"Windows" and their team. But I'd like to have them listed in my inventory once. I'd also like to avoid defining the same set of connection variables for every RHEL host or Windows host at the host level. There's one set of variables for rhel hosts, and one set of variables for windows hosts. I do not want to create child groups for the OS because I already have child groups for the host's app.

Can I simply set a variable (`os: rhel`, or `os: windows`) at the host level, and then later assign the connection variables based on the value of this `os` variable? This would need to be done before ansible tries to connect to the host.

So the logic would look something like this I think?:

1. ansible reads inventory hosts based on host pattern
2. prepare to execute on host1
3. read os value on host1
4. assign ansible connection variables for host1 based on os value for host1
5. connect to host1 using these newly assigned variables
6. execute playbook on host1

If I can do something like this, how?

edit:

A truncated example of the inventory I think I want to use:

```yaml
---
TeamOne:
  vars:
    team:
      name: <specific team named as set in a tool we use>
      id: <id>
    assignment_group: <value>
  children:
    AppOne:
      hosts:
        hostname1:
          os: rhel
          ansible_host: <ip address>
        hostname2:
          os: windows
          ansible_host: <ip_address>
      vars:
        tags:
          application_appid: <appid>
          application_name: <appname>
    AppTwo:
      hosts:
        hostname3:
          os: rhel
          ansible_host: <ip address>
        hostname4:
          os: windows
          ansible_host: <ip_address>
      vars:
        tags:
          application_appid: <appid>
          application_name: <appname>     
FoobarTeam:
  vars:
    team:
      name: <specific team named as set in a tool we use>
      id: <id>
    assignment_group: <value>
  children:
    FooApp:
      hosts:
        foohost1:
          os: rhel
          ansible_host: <ip address>
        foohost2:
          os: windows
          ansible_host: <ip_address>
      vars:
        tags:
          application_appid: <appid>
          application_name: <appname>
    BarApp:
      hosts:
        barhost1:
          os: rhel
          ansible_host: <ip address>
        barhost2:
          os: windows
          ansible_host: <ip_address>
      vars:
        tags:
          application_appid: <appid>
          application_name: <appname>
```

Now multiply that by about 20 (and growing) teams, each with a varying number of apps under them as child groups, with any number of hosts (some as low as 2, others as high as 50 or more). We're at 250 hosts and planning to have to onboard more.

Comment: Thanks for the update. At this point, consider splitting the inventory into several smaller ones. For example, group them by teams. Ansible allows to load multiple inventories at a time. That would help both to simplify their management and improve safety (i.e. you won't be able to affect the servers you didn't meant to change).

Answer (score 2):

I decided to make my answer more structural and list several ideas.

### Options that require changes to the inventory

#### Use the dynamic inventory

Since you use ServiceNow as CMDB, you may want to check out [`servicenow.itsm`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/servicenow.itsm?tab=readme-ov-file) collection that includes an inventory plugin. Using it, you would be able to retrieve the parameters from its tables.

It could also be used in combination with your existing static one.

If you experience issues with the inventory plugin itself (e.g. you have custom CMBD setup with custom tables and CI relations), you can use the API modules of that collection.

#### Define the separate groups for Windows and RHEL hosts

> I could have them in multiple groups: "RHEL"/"Windows" and their team. But I'd like to have them listed in my inventory once. I'd also like to avoid defining the same set of connection variables for every RHEL host or Windows host at the host level. There's one set of variables for rhel hosts, and one set of variables for windows hosts. I do not want to create child groups for the OS because I already have child groups for the host's app.

I understand your preference but this looks like the simplest and the most correct thing to do. You don't need to set the connection variables per host - if you have groups `windows` and `rhel`, you can set [`ansible_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_connection) as a group variable. Your inventory file could look like this:

```yaml
# inventory-canonic.yaml
---
all:
  children:
    some_group:
      hosts:
        win[1:3]:
        rhel[1:3]:
    another_group:
      hosts:
        win[4:5]:
        rhel[4:5]:
    windows:
      hosts:
        win[1:5]:
      vars:
        ansible_connection: winrm
    rhel:
      hosts:
        rhel[1:5]:
      vars:
        ansible_connection: ssh
```

> Can I simply set a variable (os: rhel, or os: windows) at the host level

Technically you can, but there's no need to: as the example above shows, Ansible has a special variable specifically for this. But setting it on host level is not a scalable approach.

#### Refactor the existing inventory

If you have a large inventory, consider splitting it into several smaller ones - they will be easier to maintain and you can set the common parameters as another separate inventory or playbook group vars. Also they would be safer to use as you will no longer target all the hosts but only ones that should be affected. It is usually recommended to split the hosts by the environment. I don't know if you use this approach, but regardless to that, distinction by the team name is also a good option. You can also use different structures:

```
inventories/
├── common
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   ├── rhel.yaml
│   │   └── windows.yaml
│   └── hosts.yaml
├── FoobarTeam
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── hosts.yaml
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── hosts.yaml
│   └── uat
│       └── hosts.yaml
└── TeamOne
    ├── AppOne.yaml
    └── AppTwo.yaml
```

### Options that don't depend on the inventory

> So the logic would look something like this I think?:
>
> 1. ansible reads inventory hosts based on host pattern

This is possible, but there are more flexible ways to achieve the same without changing the inventory.

#### SSH on Windows

First of all, Ansible supports SSH on Windows. But the documentation states that this is **still an experimental feature as of `ansible-core 2.16`**, and there are manual actions that should be performed beforehand. If it's not a problem in your environment, then the most straightforward solution is to connect to all servers using SSH, and [gather facts to handle the further differences](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

#### Attempting to detect the connection method automatically

Also, you can try to detect the connection type automatically using try-catch logic provided by `block`. I wouldn't say I like this implementation - for example, it would rely on reassigning the variables as facts. But I think it should work, and this playbook could be then imported into any other playbook (or the logic could be moved in a role):

```yaml
# playbook-autodetect-connection-type.yaml
---
- name: Detect the connection type
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Try to connect using WinRM first, then fall back to SSH
      block:
        - name: Try to connect using WinRM
          vars:
            ansible_connection: winrm
            ansible_port: 5985
          block:
            - name: Gather facts using WinRM
              setup:

            - name: Set the corresponding connection parameters for WinRM
              set_fact:
                ansible_connection: "{{ ansible_connection }}"
                ansible_port: "{{ ansible_port }}"          
      rescue:
        - name: Try to connect using SSH
          vars:
            ansible_connection: ssh
            ansible_become_method: dzdo
          block:
            - name: Gather facts using SSH
              setup:

            - name: Set the corresponding connection parameters for SSH
              set_fact:
                ansible_connection: "{{ ansible_connection }}"
                ansible_become_method: "{{ ansible_become_method }}"
      always:
        - name: Display the detected connection type
          debug:
            var: ansible_connection
```

### Options that depend on the inventory

#### Setting the connection method based on the host name

These options would require your host names to be defined in a pattern that allows to distinct them by the OS.

##### Ternary filter for simple cases

The simplest option would cover the case when you only have two possible types of connections:

```yaml
# inventory.yaml
---
all:
  children:
    some_group:
      hosts:
        win[1:3]:
        rhel[1:3]:
    another_group:
      hosts:
        win[4:5]:
        rhel[4:5]:
```

```yaml
# playbook-simplest.yaml
---
- name: Setup the hosts
  hosts: all
  connection: "{{ inventory_hostname.startswith('win') | ternary('winrm', 'ssh') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_connection
```

##### Dynamic creation of groups for more complex inventory

If you have more OS options, inline Jinja templates will become harder to develop and maintain. A better option could be to iterate over the list of hosts in the inventory and set the `ansible_connection` variable based on the host name dynamically. This approach will also give you an opportunity to target the hosts based on their OS in the subsequent plays. With the same inventory as in the previous example, the playbook would look like this:

```yaml
# playbook.yaml
---
- name: Detect the connection type
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Add host to Windows group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
        group: windows
        ansible_connection: winrm
      when: hostvars[item].inventory_hostname.startswith('win')
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"

    - name: Add host to RHEL group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ hostvars[item].inventory_hostname }}"
        group: rhel
        ansible_connection: ssh
      when: hostvars[item].inventory_hostname.startswith('rhel')
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | difference(groups['windows']) }}"

    # More conditions could be defined further

- name: Further actions
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Further tasks go here
      debug:
        var: ansible_connection
```

Comment: I'm still open to using multiple groups, I just feel like it can be tedious to make sure hosts are in both places at the same time. This is what we currently do (albeit with a json inventory) and it can be a pain when hosts need to be added or removed. 

edit: accidentally hit enter too soon lol

Comment: As for the option of setting the vars by hostname, unfortunately we can't do that. We don't have any common string in the hostnames that indicate the os they are. Best we have is the platforms they're runing (like tomcat, websphere, iis, sql, db2). Makes my life harder sadly.

Comment: Besides reducing the tediousness of having hosts listed in multiple groups, I also just kind of liked the idea of having the simple `os = rhel` variable or whatnot under each host. It's still somewhat tedious, but we have to add the `ansible_host` variable anyway, and I like that it helps users to see which kind of host it is at a glance.

Comment: I'll have to look into the SSH for Windows thing. It was a long time ago when we first started using Ansible against our Windows servers and at the time we determined we had to do it with winrm. I'm not sure if its because our windows servers don't have SSH installed/enabled in a lot of our environment or what. We're unfortunately still using a lot of <2019 servers.

But using SSH for everything would make my life a lot easier, so thanks!

Comment: Could you post your inventory to the question? I still don't understand why listing a host "twice" is an issue while adding custom variables instead of reusing the existing ones is not. Moreover, if you set `ansible_host` explicitly, you define an alias for each host, aren't you? If so, you are able to change the aliases so that they reflect the OS. As for SSH and WinRM - chances are that you won't be able to use SSH for your purposes because some modules require WinRM connection to work, so it fully depends on both the configuration and your playbook contents.

Comment: I can post a truncated example of my inventory but I can't post the whole thing as it would require anonymizing 250+ hosts. 

Listing "host" twice, when I have 250+ (and will likely grow much more this coming year) hosts makes for a very unwieldy inventory. I could break it up into group files though, for sure. But then my team has to make sure hosts are in both places (an os group and a team group) or else it won't work.

Comment: I want the alias to match the hostname while `ansible_host` is set to the IP address in case things get funky with DNS. I don't want the aliases to be customized and not match the hostname because these aren't our teams servers, they are owned by other app teams, and it would just add an unnecessary layer of complexity if we can't look them up in our CMDB because we customized an alias for them.

Comment: Is there something explicitly wrong with the method I devised and posted below? I'm still open to doing the two group method of course, just hoping to find the simplest way to manage a growing inventory for my team.

Comment: So, you're getting your inventory dynamically from the CMDB? Is there a chance that the OS could also be retrieved from there? I've noticed the `assignment_group` variable - could it be that your CMDB is ServiceNow? If so, there is a dedicated inventory plugin for it that could be tweaked to retrieve the required parameters. If the administrators did not distribute them over multiple custom tables, of course... Also, do you really need to store a static inventory in this case?

Comment: We're getting some info from the CMDB yes, but not every variable. Some of it is specific to the tool this playbook is designed to help administer. We do use ServiceNow, i'll definitely look into this plugin that could help. Currently I have a python script that pulls some information via API calls and plugs it into our json inventory (its this inventory that I want to revamp though).

Comment: I don't think we can do a purely dynamic inventory though, I'll have to research that more. We use the Ansible inventory also as a secondary record keeping thing (internal to our team) for our tool as well, so we know which hosts are supposed to have the tool installed on them, and have relevant information like the team's assignment group, contact info, app info, etc. It's not a tool installed on every host in the company .. yet.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following in my playbook to accomplish this. The key points are to disable `gather_facts` at the play level, set your ansible connection vars using `set_facts` based on the variable in your inventory, then manually run `gather_facts` with the `setup` module. After that you can write the rest of your play.

```
- name: playbook name
  hosts: TeamGroupName
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: If os is RHEL, assign RHEL connection variables
      when: os == 'rhel'
      set_fact:
        ansible_connection: ssh
        ansible_become_method: dzdo
    - name: If OS is Windows, assign Windows connection variables
      when: os == 'windows'
      set_fact:
        ansible_connection: winrm
        ansible_port: 5985
    - name: Gathering facts
      setup:
    ...rest of the playbook can now be added here...
```

Comment: You don't need to use a separate variable for that, `ansible_connection` itself is enough. You can check out my answer for details.

Comment: I understand, but this way I set just one variable in the inventory & avoid multiple groups. Otherwise, I'd have to set two variables (beccome_method for rhel, port for windows) for each host.. or use the multiple groups solution as mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

delegate_to with when clause would do the trick.

Example playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - awesome_role
```

Inventory

```
all:
  children:
    servers:
      hosts:
        server01:
          ansible_host: 1.2.3.4
        server02:
          ansible_host: 4.3.2.1
```

Awesome_role

```
└── awesome_role
    └── tasks
        ├── main.yml
        ├── rhel.yml
        └── windows.yml



$ cat awesome_role/tasks/main.yml 
- name: Set Win host
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks: windows.yml
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  delegate_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_user: admin

- name: Set RHEL host
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks: rhel.yml
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  delegate_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_user: root
    ansible_port: 2222

$ cat awesome_role/tasks/rhel.yml
- name: Gather facts
  ansible.builtin.setup:

- name: Create file
  ansible.builtin.file:
    state: touch
    path: /rhelfile
    

$ cat awesome_role/tasks/windows.yml 
- name: Create file
  ansible.builtin.file:
    state: touch
    path: /windowsfile
```

Comment: Could you explain why do you think it would work, and why would one need a role here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).